# All the permutations of $S_4$ conjugate to $(1\ 2)(3\ 4)$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I am unable to solve this problem. Find all the permutations of $S_4$ which are conjugate to $(1\ 2)(3\ 4)$ .

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  all those permutations have the following form $(ij)(kl).$